# How do i hide and show forms using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've this html

```
<div class="phoneVerification">
    <h1><span style="border-bottom:2px solid">Phone Verification</span></h1>
    <div class="phoneForm">
      <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneOTP" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send OTP</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="OTPForm">
      <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">OTP</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneOTP" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Confirm OTP</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

like this. Here, I've to display Phone form first. When i enter a number, the second form should display. Until then second form is hidden. Can you help me to solve this using Jquery.
Thank you.

Comment: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)(, [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/))

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qxunngh6/)

You can hide the second form in css

```
.form-inline.yoyo{
    display:none
}
```

and later show form using [**`.show()`**](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
$(".sendd").click(function(){
   if($("#phoneOTP").val()=="")
      alert("please enter PhoneOTP")
   else
     $(".yoyo").show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response

Comment: @SanthoshKrishna : Pleasure !! this is what you wanted ..right ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to give your form some ID to differentiate between the two forms. But after that just do a show on your div. I've given it an additional class `hidden` show you can just remove the class.

```js
$("#phoneF").submit(function() {
  $(".OTPForm").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phoneVerification">
  <h1><span style="border-bottom:2px solid">Phone Verification</span></h1>
  <div class="phoneForm">
    <form id="phoneF" class="form-inline" role="form" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneOTP" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send OTP</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="OTPForm hidden">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">OTP</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneOTP" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Confirm OTP</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhswopu5/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".phoneForm input[type=text]").on("input", function() {
   if($(this).val()!="") {
      $(".phoneForm").next().show();
   }
   else {
      $(".phoneForm").next().hide();
   }
)};
```

use the above piece of code.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp
here is the tutorial.